# EXCEL formula: can't interpret the role of an array in the formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got a formula to calculate coefficients for a linear regression. Checked out what LINEST does but cannot understand what the formula I have is doing. I am confused with the data points in the brackets `{1;2;3}`. Also the coefficients 1 and 4 seem strange. Note: there are 4 inputs (I assumed that it might be degrees of freedom). Any thoughts?

```
=INDEX(LINEST(C203:G203,$C$196:$G$196^{1;2;3}),1,4)
```

Comment: Found some explanation: https://people.stfx.ca/bliengme/ExcelTips/Polynomial.htm

Comment: `INDEX`'s first parameter takes a matrix, outputed through your `LINEST` function (don't forget it's an array formula entered through Ctrl+Shift+Enter). The second parameter asks from which row `INDEX` should return a value from this matrix, whereas the third parameter takes a columnnumber. So step through evaluation and process the formula step-by-step to check which value you actually need. Helpfull? Note: I've never used `LINEST` but your question is also about these `1` and `4` values.

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out how it works. Anyway, thanks for your input!